# What's the difference between align-content and align-items?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, alignment

What is the difference between `align-items` and `align-content`?

Comment: [align items](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/) and [align content](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/)

Comment: I already also digged Chris's Almanac but still did not get clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276

Comment: I am never going to truly understand this one :-/

Comment: align-content manages the space between the lines when items wrap. align-items aligns the items relative to each other when sizes of items are different.  When the size of the items are the same and there is only one line, they behave similarly.

Answer (score 725):

The `align-items` property of flex-box aligns the items inside a flex container along the cross axis just like `justify-content` does along the main axis. (For the default `flex-direction: row` the cross axis corresponds to vertical and the main axis corresponds to horizontal. With `flex-direction: column` those two are interchanged respectively).

Here's an example of how `align-items:center` looks:

[image: align-items: center]

But `align-content` is for multi line flexible boxes. It has no effect when items are in a single line. It aligns the whole structure according to its value. Here's an example for `align-content: space-around;`:
[image]

And here's how `align-content: space-around;` with `align-items:center` looks: [image]

Note the 3rd box and all other boxes in first line change to vertically centered in that line.

Here are some codepen links to play with:

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/MKQWbb

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/WrMNWR

[Here's](http://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/) a super cool pen which shows and lets you play with almost everything in flexbox.

Comment: Note that the `align-*` properties can also shift flex items horizontally. It depends on the `flex-direction`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: > "But align-content is for multi line flexible boxes. It has no effect when items are in a single line" -- this appears to not be true, or not be honoured, in latest Firefox (May 2020). Instead, if there's a single flex-line (all content fits within less than the main-axis length) which is less than full height (cross-axis size is less than full available), then align-content *if set* will obliterate align-items. This makes sense: it applies to ANY lines it finds?

Comment: React native layout arrangement is a joke. The property terms are so misleading! Its just my personal opinion after dealing with much, much simpler layout android SDK offers 

Comment: You said that align-items is like justify-content, but in the perpendicular axis. Then why it don't have values like “space-evenly”? Also, You said align-content only works in multi-line flex but for me, it's also working on single line flex. Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/Utsav_0/pen/oNMKZXV

Answer (score 249):

From the example at [flexboxfroggy.com](https://flexboxfroggy.com):

It will take you 10-20 minutes and at level 21 you will find the answer to your question.

> **align-content** determines the spacing between lines
>
> **align-items** determines how the items as a whole are aligned within the container.
>
> When there is only one line, **align-content** has no effect

Comment: Indeed, I did find the froggy example really useful. Learned a lot from it.

Comment: Actually, `align-content` does have effect for a single line content, too, if the container has non-shrink-wrap height (that is, container is higher than any of the child items). The `align-items` positions each child relative to the line of content and  `align-content` positions each line of content relative to the container. And the names are "align" and "justify" because the real orientation depends on `flex-flow`. I'd prefer "parallel" and "orthogonal" instead.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: I don't observe any effect of `align-content` on single line/column flex content. Also, MDN disagrees with you (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).

Comment: @wortwart See demo at https://jsfiddle.net/n2ruogLt/ – note how row with letters a,b,c,d end up at the end of the container even when it doesn't have `align-content`.

Comment: @Spikatrix I couldnt finish level 24. Certain things didnt seem to have effect anymore like changing justify-content

Comment: According to Chrome Dev tool: "The flex-wrap: nowrap property prevents align-content from having an effect.  Try setting flex-wrap to something other than nowrap."

Comment: in case for people who wants to see how the level 21 look like - https://imgur.com/a/QNpWbuc

Answer (score 91):

First, `align-items` is for items in a single row. So for a single row of elements on **main axis**, `align-items` will align these items respective of each other and it will start with fresh perspective from the next row.

Now, `align-content` doesn't interfere with items in a row but **with rows itself**. Hence, `align-content` will try to align rows with respect to each other and flex container.

Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/htym5zkn/8/

Comment: So for a flex-direction of row, does align content only do something if the flexbox has a height set and therefore doesn't just use the child element's height leaving no room to add space between/around the rows?

Answer (score 41):

I had the same confusion. After some tinkering based on many of the answers above, I can finally see the differences. In my humble opinion, the distinction is best demonstrated with a flex container that satisfies the following two conditions:

1. The flex container itself has a height constraint (e.g., `min-height: 60rem`) and thus can become ***too tall*** for its content
2. The child items enclosed in the container have ***uneven heights***

---

**Condition 1** helps me understand what `content` means relative to its parent container. When the content is flush with the container, we will not be able to see any positioning effects coming from `align-content`. It is only when we have extra space along the cross axis, we start to see its effect: It aligns the content relative to the boundaries of the parent container.

**Condition 2** helps me visualize the effects of `align-items`: it aligns items relative to each other.

---

Here is a code example. Raw materials come from [Wes Bos' CSS Grid tutorial](https://cssgrid.io/) (21. Flexbox vs. CSS Grid)

- Example HTML:

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Longerrrrrrrrrrrrrr</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item" id="tall">This is Many Words</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">Snickers</div>
    <div class="item">Wes Is Cool</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
  </div>
```

- Example CSS:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*dictates a min-height*/
  min-height: 60rem;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 5px solid white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
 }

#tall {
  /*intentionally made tall*/
  min-height: 30rem;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 10rem;
}
```

---

**Example 1**: Let's narrow the viewport so that the content is flush with the container. This is when `align-content: flex-start;` has no effects since the entire content block is tightly fit inside the container (no extra room for repositioning!)

Also, note the 2nd row--see how the items are center aligned among themselves.

[image]

**Example 2**: As we widen the viewport, we no longer have enough content to fill the entire container. Now we start to see the effects of `align-content: flex-start;`--it aligns the content relative to the top edge of the container.
[image]

---

These examples are based on flexbox, but the same principles are applicable to CSS grid. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Shoutout to wesbos ? :P

Comment: Fantastic explanation. `Condition 1` and `Condition 2` were what was missing from most of the other explanations here. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The effect of both `align-items` and `align-content` is along the **cross-axis**.

Let say if `flex-direction` is `row` then the main axis is `Left to Right` and if `flex-direction` is `column` then the main axis is from `top to bottom`.

So In the below examples, we gonna assume that `flex-direction` is `row` i.e. main axis is from Left to Right and cross-axis is from top to bottom.

> `align-content` only works if there is `flex-wrap: wrap` and if there is more than one `flex-line` in container.

> `align-content` has higher priority than `align-items` if there are multiple flex-line.

**What is flex-line?**

Each row or column of flex items in a flex container is a flex line. Multiple lines occur when there is not enough space in a container and flex-items would take the next line(in `flex-direction: row;`) to fit in. In `flex-direction: column` it will add flex items to next line.

[example](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/xxgxmZJ?editors=1100)

By default, the flex is a flexible container i.e. it can accommodate any number of elements unless we have specified `flex-wrap: wrap`. Without wrap, flex-items will overflow the container(if `flex-direction` is `row`).

**align-content example**

```css
.container{
  border: 5px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.box{
  height:100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.box1{
  background: purple;
}

.box2{
  background:   #ff8c00;
}

.box3{
  background: lime;
}

.box4{
  background: #008080;
}

.box5{
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box box3">box 3</div>
  <div class="box box4">box 4</div>
  <div class="box box5">box 5</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, If there would have been `flex-wrap: no-wrap` then `align-content` doesn't affect our layout.

---

**align-items example**

The align-items property determines how flex items are positioned within a flex line, along the cross-axis.

```css
.container{
  border: 5px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box{
  height:100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.box1{
  background: purple;
}

.box2{
  background:   #ff8c00;
}

.box3{
  background: lime;
}

.box4{
  background: #008080;
}

.box5{
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box box3">box 3</div>
  <div class="box box4">box 4</div>
  <div class="box box5">box 5</div>
</div>
```

> If `align-content` and `align-items` are declared on a container with properties `flex-wrap: wrap` and if there are more than flex-line then `align-content` property has higher priority than `align-items`.

**`align-content`  and `align-items` priority example**

```css
.container{
  border: 5px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.box{
  height:100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.box1{
  background: purple;
}

.box2{
  background:   #ff8c00;
}

.box3{
  background: lime;
}

.box4{
  background: #008080;
}

.box5{
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box box3">box 3</div>
  <div class="box box4">box 4</div>
  <div class="box box5">box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Well I have examined them on my browser.

`align-content` can change a line's height for row direction or width for column when it's value is stretch, or add empty space between or around the lines for `space-between`, `space-around`, `flex-start`, `flex-end values`.

`align-items` can change items height or position inside the line's area. When items are not wrapped they have only one line which it's area is always stretched to the flex-box area (even if the items overflow), and `align-content` has no effect on a single line. So it has no effect on items that are not wrapped and only `align-items` can change items position or stretch them when all of them are on a single line.

However, if they are wrapped you have multiple lines and items inside each line. And if all items of each line have the same height (for row direction) that line's height will be equal to those items height and you don't see any effect by changing `align-items` value.

So if you want to affect items by `align-items` when your items are wrapped and have the same height (for row direction) first you have to use `align-content` with stretch value in order to expand the lines area.

Answer (score 12):

Having read some of the answers, they identify correctly that `align-content` takes no affect if the flex content is not wrapped. However what they don't understand is `align-items` still plays an important role when there is wrapped content:

In the following two examples, `align-items` is used to center the items **within each** row, then we change `align-content` to see it's effect.

### Example 1:

```
align-content: flex-start;
```

[image]

### Example 2:

```
    align-content: flex-end;
```

[image]

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child" style="height: 30px;">1</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50px;">2</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 60px;">3</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 40px;">4</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50px;">5</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 20px;">6</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 90px;">7</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 50px;">8</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 30px;">9</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 40px;">10</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 30px;">11</div>
    <div class="child" style="height: 60px;">12</div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-end;
    background: lightgray;
    height: 400px;
}
.child {
    padding: 12px;
    background: red;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

**align-content**

`align-content` controls the cross-axis (i.e. vertical direction if the `flex-direction` is `row`, and horizontal if the `flex-direction` is `column`) positioning of *multiple* lines relative to each other.

(Think lines of a paragraph being vertically spread out, stacked toward the top, stacked toward the bottom. This is under a `flex-direction` row paradigm).

**align-items**

`align-items` controls the cross-axis  of an individual line of flex elements.

(Think how an individual line of a paragraph is aligned, if it contains some normal text and some taller text like math equations. In that case, will it be the bottom, top, or center of each type of text in a line that will be aligned?)

Answer (score 7):

The key property is **flex-wrap**. When *nowrap* (or when there is no extra space in the cross axis), **align-content** has no effect. When *wrap* or *wrap-reverse*, it has always an effect (**regardless of the line count**) if there is extra space in the cross axis.

Compare these four boxes:

[image: align-content vs align-items]

Answer (score 5):

*align-items* spreads the child elements vertically with space between them.

*align-content* bunches them together as if they were one element.

(if the flex-direction is column)

Comment: It depends on flex direction, its not always vertical

Comment: It's amazing how stubbornly people resist the notion that `flex-direction` can be changed.

Answer (score 4):

What I have learned from every answer and visiting the blog is

> what is the cross axis and main axis

- main axis is horizontal row and cross axis is vertical column - for `flex-direction: row`
- main axis is vertical column and cross axis is horizontal row - for `flex-direction: column`

> Now align-content and align-items

**align-content** is for the row, it works if the container has (more than one row)
Properties of align-content

```
.container {
  align-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly | stretch | start | end | baseline | first baseline | last baseline + ... safe | unsafe;
}
```

**align-items** is for the items in row
Properties of align-items

```
.container {
  align-items: stretch | flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | first baseline | last baseline | start | end | self-start | self-end + ... safe | unsafe;
}
```

For more reference visit to [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

while **align-items** would centre as **a single line of text both horizontally and vertically inside a container** , **align-content** would behave as if there were **multiple lines of text,or a paragraph**, and **start from top aligning even a single line of text as if it were  paragraph which has been given a  text-align: center rule.**

[image]

This is the result we get from

```
align-content:center;
```

Comment: Your example isn’t useful without specifying what flex direction you referring to

Answer (score 2):

**First Part**

**align-items** applies to single line of boxes only. Suppose there are 4 boxes in a single line inside the container. then **align-items** will be applied to align those boxes in a single line. If flex-direction is row (which is default) then align-items will arrange the boxes vertically, if its column then arrange the boxes horizontally.

**Second Part**

Continuing with the above single line of boxes, if we add one more line of 4 boxes, now there are 8 boxes, 4 in each line. Here **align-content** comes into picture, if we apply **align-content** to the container, it will be applied to both lines having total of 8 boxes. If we apply **align-content:center**, it will center both lines in a container. In that sense **align-content** is used to arrange multi line flexible boxes.

align-items: center, align-content: flex-start
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The main difference is when the height of the elements are not the same!
Then you can see how in the row, they are all center\end\start

Comment: This does not explain the difference.

Answer (score -2):

according to what I understood from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-columns-rows):

when you use align-item or justify-item, you are adjusting "the content inside a grid item along the column axis or row axis respectively.

But:
if you use align-content or justify-content, you are setting the position a grid along the column axis or the row axis. it occurs when you have a grid in a bigger container and width or height are inflexible (using px).

Comment: This is inaccurate and confusing. align-items is not fixed to controlling the column, but dependings on the flex-direction. Similarly align-content is not only for column axis, and justify-content is not only for the row axis. justify-itemS has nothing to do with flex box.