# Flex box align-content doesn't leave space between items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I referred the material about flexbox `align-content` in these two places, [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

And i tried to place three horizontal bars of different colors with 100% height and equal amount of spacing between them.

For the flex container, i set `align-content` as `space-between`. But still, all stripes are closely packed with no space between.

How can i force the empty space below the stripes to be distributed in-between & around equally?

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bs5BA5e6lPhLMoLJhlr1?p=preview).

```html
<body style="height:100%;">
  <div style="display:flex;height:100%;background-color:#cccccc;flex-direction:column;align-content:space-between;">
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:#222222;width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:#777777; width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:pink; width:100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D is correct. Especially with your high rep level, such a low-quality question is a bit surprising. I've edited because the fundamental question isn't bad and future visitors may benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set `height: 100%` on html and next you should use `justify-content: space-between;`.

By default `flex-direction` is `row` and **main axis** is left-to right so `justify-content` position elements along main axis or horizontally. But when you change `flex-direction` to `column` now main axis is changed to top to bottom and `justify-content` position elements still along main-axis but now its vertically.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:100%;">
  <div style="display:flex;height:100%;background-color:#cccccc;flex-direction:column;justify-content:space-between;">
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:#222222;width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:#777777; width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:pink; width:100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks Nenad.. i thought, justify-content centers horizontally always.. looks like, justify-content centers along main-axis...

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanation, i hope it helps.