# Flexbox align-content not consistent with variable number of items

Tags: css, flexbox

In my application the number of items in a flex container is variable, and I want them to be both vertically and horizontally centred. I'm doing this by using `justify-content` for horizontal centring, and `align-content` for vertical centring.

However, reading from [CSS Tricks' almanac](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/) states the following:

> Note, this property has no effect when the flexbox has only a single line.

This becomes quickly apparent in my application. While there aren't enough items to wrap onto another line, vertical centring from `align-content` doesn't work at all.

As soon as a second line of content appears, `align-content` kicks in and works as expected.

I'm sure there's a reason for this behaviour, however in my case the result is an inconsistent user experience.

I know that I can achieve vertical centring by other means, for instance by wrapping the entire container in another flexbox, or a table, and applying vertical centring there. However, I feel like there should be a better way?

**Is there some other flexbox option I'm missing that would solve this problem without introducing more HTML elements?** If so, what is that option? :P

Comment: Use `align-items` instead of `align-content` might help ... still, need to know which flex direction you use and so on...

Comment: Thanks for all the `align-items` references. It didn't solve the problem on its own (because the behaviour is quite different to `align-content` when you have multiple lines of content), however I found that combining both `align-items` and `align-content` did. I will write an answer with more details (and examples) soon.

Comment: You need to use both, `align-content` and `align-items`. It's explained in the duplicate.

Comment: @Michael_B I suggest you close it as a dupe, since I can't see how anyone can explain that any better than you already did :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given facts, you should use `align-items` instead of `align-content`

Notes:

- `align-content` works on multi line flexboxes, very well described here: [Whats the difference between align-content and align-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items)
- Based on the flex direction, `justify-content` and `align-items` alignment direction changes

---

Column-based

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;           /*  center vertical    */
  align-items: center;               /*  center horizontal  */
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray
}

.flex * {
  margin-bottom: 0;         /* removed margin at one side since they 
                               doesn't collapse when flexbox is used */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <h1>Hey</h1>
  <p>How are</p>
  <p>we doing</p>

</div>
```

Row-based

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;           /*  center horizontal  */
  align-items: center;               /*  center vertical    */
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <h1>Hey </h1>
  <p>How are </p>
  <p>we doing</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `align-items` & `justify-content` together will vertically and horizontally center a single item:

`align-items:center; justify-content:center`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zk4bkk/