# align-content: center not working in Chrome

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, text-align

I am trying to vertically align divs with flexbox, by using the *align-content: center*. It works fine in Firefox and IE, but it does not vertically align in Chrome. In Chrome the divs stays on top.

```
<div class="products-wrapper">
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.products-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* FLEX */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.product {
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.product img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

I have also been trying *align-items: center;* which centers the divs vertically, but it will not be a straight line with the images and text if I have different amount of text for example.

Anyone with a solution how to vertically center divs (straight), which works in all browsers?

Image example:

[image: Image example]

**Edit:** If you don't need the height to be dynamic, *align-items: center;* will work with (for example) *max-height: 400px;* on the .product div. Not really what I wanted though.

Comment: I see the problem is not that the `product` elements don't _align_ in the same way, but they get a 100% height in Chrome. Not yet sure why.

Comment: It seems that if you will set height to .product you will solve it?

Comment: @A.Meshu If you know what the height of the products needs to be, sure.

Comment: @A.Meshu Yes, it works if the height is set in stone. But there must be a better solution which works dynamically.

Comment: Since the amount of text dinamically change, i can't think of something else but setting it (and handle overflow etc).

Comment: This post may help you understand the problem and provide a solution: [*How does `flex-wrap` work with `align-self`, `align-items` and `align-content`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you'll need to use `align-items: flex-start`, this way all items will be aligned to the top of their line. And to center vertically you're looking for the `align-items: center` property which aligns the items in the flex container along the cross axis, which in your case you'll have to use in an outer wrapper to make sure the `products` div is centered in the page.

The `align-content: center` property comes into play only when there is more than one line (wrapped content).

A better explanation about the difference between those two properties is in the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items)

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.products-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    /* FLEX */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gray;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.product {
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
}

.product img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div class="products-wrapper">
      <div class="product">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/St._Bernard_puppy.jpg/120px-St._Bernard_puppy.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/St._Bernard_puppy.jpg/120px-St._Bernard_puppy.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/St._Bernard_puppy.jpg/120px-St._Bernard_puppy.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like I said in my post, I have tried this. It will not horizontally align properly in a straight line depending on how much text there is in the <p>.

Comment: @Nifel, You need to use an additional wrapper flex to achieve what you want, look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Make the `.product` element, flex container. This so you can align the content inside them.

```
.product {
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

```css
.products-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* FLEX */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.product {
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.product img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-wrapper">
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <img src="images/temporary.jpg" alt="Temporary">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work when there is a different amount of text in the <p> for example. It will not go in a straight line. So the problem persists.

Comment: could you please elaborate the issue

Comment: The divs will vertically align, but not horizontally. It will go like __-_-_- instead of ----------

Comment: @Nifel Sorry i am not undertanding the issue. Can you maybe add the content that generate therror.

Comment: I added an image link in the issue description. As you can see it does not look good when trying to align vertically in flexbox.