# Unable to Centre a div inside a JS rendered div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to use particle effect in the background and have some text centred in that div and have the particle effect in the background.
The javascript files refer to the `particleJS` files which you can find here.[Github ParticleJS](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/archive/2.0.0.zip).
But Im just not able to centre it in the middle, is it because JS is rendering it simultaneously is there a way I can do it.
[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/badaruddinshaikh/pen/XLezxe)

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas{
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

#particles-js{
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#name{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" href = "particle.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
 <title>Linko</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="particles-js">
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
 <div id="name">
  <p>Hello there</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Text seems to be centered

Comment: its centred in its own div I want it to be centred inside the `particles-js`

Comment: You have to post a snippet reproducing the problem, this is not enough

Comment: Sir the JS files are huge you can visit the GitHub link up there, I Hope you understand that getting a files that huge poses formatting problems, I can still try if you want it here

Comment: here is the like to the code pen https://codepen.io/badaruddinshaikh/pen/XLezxe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: absolute;` to the #name div for him to go above the canvas.
Then change `align-content:center` by `align-items:center` in #particles-js div.

Here is a updated codepen :)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqWePJ

The `position:absolute` is needed because HTML element by default (`posistion:static`) are positioned as a flow, one after another in their parents, so you can't have one overlapping another. Adding the `position:absolute` to one of the element will remove it from this flow, and position it as if it was alone in his parent, so now it can overlap the others.
You can see this link for more complet explanations on CSS positionning.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

For the `align-content`/`align-items` issue, `align-content` is used for multi line alignement, and `align-items` for alignement in the inverse of the flex box direction.
The naming here is discutable and a bit confusing since `justify-content` is used for single line alignement in the flex box direction I think, but I was not here during this discussion, they probably had a reason to do it this way.
You can see this question [What's the difference between align-content and align-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items) for more details on that.

Comment: Hey thank You for the solution that solved my problem, but can you tell me where was I going wrong,?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
#name{
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
}
```

This will cause the 'name' div to be horizontally centered inside of the 'particles-js' div.