# i have a problem with the location of the content in React Native. How can I move the hello world sentence to the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

How can I move the hello world sentence to the middle of the screen

Here are my codes:

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

export default function App(){
  return(
    <View style = {StyleSheet.container}>
      <Text> Hello World</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

{/* stylings of react native*/}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:"blue", 
    alignContent:"center",
    justifyContent:"center"
  }
})
```

result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkO9v.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
return(
    <View style = {styles.container}>  // <-- CHANGE THIS
      <Text> Hello World</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the text to be in the center horizontally you have to use `alignItems:"center"` instead of `alignContent:"center"`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items) post in case you want more information about the diffence between the two.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You are doing 2 things wrong

1. [StyleSheet](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet) is an API to create styles. You cannot use it to access styles defined inside create method. Instead you need to use `styles` variable instead.

```js
<View style={StyleSheet.container}> // ❌
<View style={styles.container}> // ✅
```

2. You need to use `alignItems` instead of `alignContent` to centrally align the Text inside View.

```js
alignContent:"center", // ❌
alignItems:"center", // ✅
```