# Scaling images inside div when page is shrunk

Tags: html, image, resize, scale, inline

Been trying to get these to scale, they need to stay on the same line and then scale.  I got the top image on the page and everything else to scale just not these images.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

[Contact Page](http://www.golden-wand.com/members/contact.php)

```
<div id="bannerImage">
   <div id="bannerImage1"><img src="../Assets/Pictures/Golden Wand/CutOut/Tools.png" width="auto" height="200px" alt="Tools"></div>
   <div id="bannerImage2"><img src="../Assets/Pictures/Golden Wand/CutOut/Angled Truck.png" width="auto" height="200px" alt="Truck"></div>
</div>
```

[CSS Style Sheet](http://www.golden-wand.com/members/styles.css)

```
div#bannerImage {border:solid purple;
    width:100%;
    height:222px;
    display:table;
}

div#bannerImage1 {border:solid red;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left:130px;
    max-height:200px;
    max-width:40%;
    display:table-cell;
}
#bannerImage1 img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
div#bannerImage2 {border:solid blue;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left:150px;
    max-height:200px;
    max-width:50%;
    display:table-cell;
}
#bannerImage2 img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer over here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103622/auto-resize-image-in-css-flexbox-layout-and-keeping-aspect-ratio) it was answer by Omega and they provided an example using [jsfiddle.net](http://goo.gl/cUoPL0)