# CSS object-fit: contain; is keeping original image width in layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, object-fit

I'm trying to make my images responsive inside some flexbox containers using `object-fit: contain`, and while the images do resize, the layout seems to be keeping the original image size, causing a scrollbar to appear.

Checking the width of the image using Chrome Dev Tools shows that the width is still 1024 (however the height has been reduced appropriately.)

(I've taken inspiration from [Auto Resize Image in CSS FlexBox Layout and keeping Aspect Ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341550/895810)
 to get to this point)

Am I missing some additional CSS attributes?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6hgqf18/1/

[image: problem]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, in fact my question used information I got from those answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103622/auto-resize-image-in-css-flexbox-layout-and-keeping-aspect-ratio

Comment: I agree, it's not a duplicate. There is nothing there explaining how and why `object-fit` behave like so. It's not about auto resize images which is already done here. it's about "why object-fit behave like this".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have is logical, you simply need to understand how `object-fit` works. Let's start with an easier example:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
}
img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 object-fit:contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069">
</div>
```

As you can see I have used a `300x200` image that I stretch inside the `300x300` box thus I break its ratio and if you check the width/height of the image you will see that it's dimension is still `300x300` (the dimenstion before applying `object-fit`).

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-fit):

> The object-fit property specifies how **the contents** of a replaced element should be fitted to the box **established by its used height and width**.

Basically, we *visually* change the content of the image so it fit the space established by the image. `object-fit` doesn't change the size of the image but uses that size as a reference to change its content inside.

Let's take the same example and use `50%` instead:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
}
img {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 object-fit:contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069">
</div>
```

Now the image has a dimension of `150x150` and inside this we change the content to have the *contain* effect.

Same logic will happen with all the values

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
}
img {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069" style="object-fit:contain;">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069" style="object-fit:cover;">
</div>
```

---

In you example you are having the same thing. without `object-fit` the image is like below

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

img {
  /*object-fit: contain;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding `object-fit` won't change its size but only what we see:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the other issue is that your image has a width of `1024px` and a flex items will not [stretch past its content size due to the `min-width` constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size) so what you need to add in order to obtain the needed effect is `min-width:0`. Doing so you will no more have overflow issue then your image will be contained inside the area defined by the flexbox layout.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0; /*added*/
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 0; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also have the same output considering `background-image` and `background-size:contain` where you no more have to bother with the `min-width` contraint since there is no more content

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  background:url(https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg) center/contain no-repeat;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. I just wish we could force the img to update its intrinsic size (in this case width) to reflect the scaled-down content so there's no extra "padding".

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `img` tag with a `div` with `width: 100%` and set image `height` to `100%` and do that without `object-fit`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-containers {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.page-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.page-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}


.img-container {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-containers">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src='https://i.imgur.com/tqQvuFr.jpg' />
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```