# How can you resize an img using css, specifically flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to place 3 images on the same row using flexbox. I also want to change the size of the first image as it is too big. However, my CSS rules are not being applied properly. I have the images each inside their own div with a class of flex-item-3 to indicate that they are flex items inside my flex container. However, I can't seem to override the default CSS rules.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif', 'arial';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("img/truck.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.flex-item {
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item1 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.logo {
  height: 90px;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: orange;
}

.flex2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  color: #312c2c;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second-flex-item p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #312c2c;
}

.second-flex-item h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.flex-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex-3-items {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrapper">

  <header class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item item1">
      <img src="Resources/img/moBurgerzLogo.png" class="logo">
    </div>
    <nav class="flex-item main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Order now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero">
      <h2>Best Burgers <br> In DA City(D.C)</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn" btn-full>Order now!</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn" btn-ghost>View Menu!</a>
    </div>

  </header>

  <section class="flex-2">
    <div class="flex-item-2 second-flex-item">
      <h2>Established in 2017 in D.M.V</h2>
      <p class="story"> moBurgerz was founded in 2017 by owner Mahamed Ibrahim.<br> Since then we have been serving the best hand crafted burgers in the D.M.V.<br>All our meat is halal and all of our ingridients are organic.</p>
      <img src="Resources/img/white_truck.jpeg" class="truck-img">
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="flex-3">

    <div class="flex-3-item meal-photos photo-1">
      <img src="Resources/img/cheeseSteak.jpg">

    </div>

    <div class="flex-3-item meal-photos">
      <img src="Resources/img/goodMoanin.jpeg">
    </div>


    <div class="flex-3-item meal-photos">
      <img src="Resources/img/moGul.jpeg">
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`.flex-3-item img { max-width:100%; }` should do the trick.

Also, look at this: [Auto Resize Image in CSS FlexBox Layout and keeping Aspect Ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103622/auto-resize-image-in-css-flexbox-layout-and-keeping-aspect-ratio)